# How do I pass a file path in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an image to show on the screen. I have the image file and code file in the same folder. I tried using the image file name and it said that there is no such file or directory. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you post some code examples along with the error?

Comment: How exactly did you try it? Please, provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: well that depends on your code.. each package does it diffrently

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to write absolute path. you can use following code

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()

abs_path = path + img_name
```